# Shared libraries and different linux systems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, shared-library

Is it possible to use a shared library, compiled for example on a RedHat / CentOS system, on a Ubuntu system?

Comment: In principle yes, but make sure of your dependencies.

Comment: Reference link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774920/can-i-use-a-shared-library-compiled-on-ubuntu-on-a-redhat-linux-machine

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

For the library's machine code to *be executed* the only requirement is for the architecture for which the library was compiled to be compatible with the Ubuntu machine's architecture.

Meaning that if the RedHat / CentOS library was compiled e.g. for x86-64 the Ubuntu machine's architecture must be x86-64 (or compatible) as well.

For the library to *be functional*, as Dani_I remarks in the comments, potential dependencies of the library must be satisfied.

Meaning that if the RedHat / CentOS library depends on other libraries, the Ubuntu machine's linker must be able to find the same libraries (or compatible ones) somewhere in the system; speaking of where those libraries are to be found, that depends strictly on the Ubuntu machine's linker's configuration.